# sched_getattr: Function not implemented

Tags: system-calls

I want to call new added syscall, sched_getattr.
However, it gives me an error.

```
int rc = syscall(SYS_sched_getattr, getpid(), &attr, sizeof(attr), 0);

./sched_getattr
sched_attr: Function not implemented
```

How can I add sched_getattr? Do I need to change some kernel configuration?

Answer (score 1):

As the [Linux Manual Page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setattr.2.html) suggests that:

**These system calls first appeared in Linux 3.14.**

You are probably running a kernel less than 3.14. Upgrade your kernel and the system call will work fine.